# Comparing two maps

Tags: java, dictionary

I have two maps declared as `Map<String, Object>`. The `Object` here could be another `Map<String, Object>` (and so on). I want to check if two maps are exactly the same without knowing their depth. Instead of using recursion can I compare the output of the `toString()` called on each map? Or is there a simpler way to compare the maps?

Comment: may be this is dumb for others, yet it is important for you, so it becomes respectable and important at the end.

Comment: Using `toString()` would fail if the map entries came out in different orders, which is entirely possible.

Comment: @user3580294 If one map was a `TreeMap` and the other was a `HashMap` (included example in my answer :-) .

Comment: `.toString()` itself would have recursive behaviour. Why do you hate it?

Comment: @maythesource.com Yeah, realized the flaw with my comment really soon after I posted it, but for some reason didn't get a notification for your response... In any case, I initially thought that OP was talking about `HashMap` instances because my reading skills are terrible, but then realized that even for those what I said wasn't true. It was after that that I realized that OP just has `Map` instances. In any case, you are correct.

Comment: @Rhymoid he's probably referring to *implementing* recursion rather than the concept itself - a feeling which I can sympathise with :)

Comment: @jammypeach ... nope, still a mystery to me. A programmer who hates recursion is like a carpenter who hates saws.

Comment: @Rhymoid I wouldn't argue with that - but I meant he might hate using it. So a carpenter who hates *using* saws. He doesn't have to like it although as you point out, he is obliged to use it from time to time.

Comment: @jammypeach I think that analogy is flawed. Though am perfectly fine with writing recursions (http://goo.gl/suHFhT) I just don't like it cause it feels messy and I have a lot of other alternatives but on the other hand this is not true for a carpenter :-)

Comment: @noMAD yeah it's pretty shoddy as analogies go :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### Quick Answer

You should use the `equals` method since this is implemented to perform the comparison you want. `toString()` itself uses an iterator just like `equals` but it is a more inefficient approach. Additionally,  as @Teepeemm pointed out, `toString` is affected by order of elements (basically iterator return order) hence is not guaranteed to provide the same output for 2 different maps (especially if we compare two different maps).

**Note/Warning**: Your question and my answer assume that classes implementing the map interface respect expected `toString` and `equals` behavior. The default java classes do so, but a custom map class needs to be examined to verify expected behavior.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

```
boolean equals(Object o)
```

> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true
>   if the given object is also a map and the two maps **represent the same
>   mappings**. More formally, **two maps m1 and m2 represent the same
>   mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())**. This ensures that the
>   equals method works properly across different implementations of the
>   Map interface.

### Implementation in Java Source (java.util.AbstractMap)

Additionally, java itself takes care of iterating through all elements and making the comparison so you don't have to. Have a look at the implementation of `AbstractMap` which is used by classes such as `HashMap`:

```
 // Comparison and hashing

    /**
     * Compares the specified object with this map for equality.  Returns
     * <tt>true</tt> if the given object is also a map and the two maps
     * represent the same mappings.  More formally, two maps <tt>m1</tt> and
     * <tt>m2</tt> represent the same mappings if
     * <tt>m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())</tt>.  This ensures that the
     * <tt>equals</tt> method works properly across different implementations
     * of the <tt>Map</tt> interface.
     *
     * <p>This implementation first checks if the specified object is this map;
     * if so it returns <tt>true</tt>.  Then, it checks if the specified
     * object is a map whose size is identical to the size of this map; if
     * not, it returns <tt>false</tt>.  If so, it iterates over this map's
     * <tt>entrySet</tt> collection, and checks that the specified map
     * contains each mapping that this map contains.  If the specified map
     * fails to contain such a mapping, <tt>false</tt> is returned.  If the
     * iteration completes, <tt>true</tt> is returned.
     *
     * @param o object to be compared for equality with this map
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if the specified object is equal to this map
     */
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Map))
            return false;
        Map<K,V> m = (Map<K,V>) o;
        if (m.size() != size())
            return false;

        try {
            Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
                K key = e.getKey();
                V value = e.getValue();
                if (value == null) {
                    if (!(m.get(key)==null && m.containsKey(key)))
                        return false;
                } else {
                    if (!value.equals(m.get(key)))
                        return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException unused) {
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

### Comparing two different types of Maps

`toString` fails miserably when comparing a `TreeMap` and `HashMap` though `equals` does compare contents correctly.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("2", "whatever2");
map.put("1", "whatever1");
TreeMap<String, Object> map2 = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
map2.put("2", "whatever2");
map2.put("1", "whatever1");

System.out.println("Are maps equal (using equals):" + map.equals(map2));
System.out.println("Are maps equal (using toString().equals()):"
        + map.toString().equals(map2.toString()));

System.out.println("Map1:"+map.toString());
System.out.println("Map2:"+map2.toString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
Are maps equal (using equals):true
Are maps equal (using toString().equals()):false
Map1:{2=whatever2, 1=whatever1}
Map2:{1=whatever1, 2=whatever2}
```

Comment: does lambda expression make the condition better?

Comment: @Kick Buttowski What do you mean?

Comment: you said answering this question is complicated and since I try to learn Lambda experssion in Java, I was wondering to know if using lambda experssion would help?

Comment: @KickButtowski I am not on Java 8 yet but am sure if I flatten the map it becomes trivial :)

Comment: @noMAD what you mean by flatten the map, it becomes trivial?

Comment: Ready made functions make this trivial so we don't need to reimplement the code. Removed the complicated mention :-) .

Comment: @KickButtowski Here is clojure example of flattening a map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901933/flattening-a-map-by-join-the-keys

Comment: The rewriting with lambda would be something like `entrySet().stream().allMatch( e -> { K key = ... }`.  It would only save a few lines.

Comment: It should be emphasized that even if both maps have the same type, i.e. both are `HashMap`s, there is no guaranty that the iteration order will be the same, hence, comparing the `toString()` result will fail. The encountered order is an implementation detail that depends on the key’s hashcodes *and* the current capacity (which might differ, even if the size is the same), further, entries being stored in the same array element (aka having a hash collision) are linked in an order depending on the *history* of the map, i.e. insertion order or whether there were removals of other keys, etc.

Answer (score 11):

As long as you override `equals()` on each key and value contained in the map, then `m1.equals(m2)` should be reliable to check for maps equality.

The same result can be obtained also by comparing `toString()` of each map as you suggested, but using `equals()` is a more intuitive approach.

May not be your specific situation, but if you store arrays in the map, may be a little tricky, because they must be compared value by value, or using `Arrays.equals()`. More details about this see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082416/equality-between-2-hashmap).

Answer (score 0):

## Comparing two Maps:

declare:

```
enum Activity{
    ADDED,
    REMOVED,
    MODIFIED
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
static class FileStateRow {
    String key;
    String value;
    Activity activity;
}

BiFunction<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>, Map<String, FileStateRow>> 
mapCompare = (newMap, oldMap) -> {
    Map<String, FileStateRow> resMap = new HashMap<>();
    newMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (!oldMap.containsKey(k)) {
            System.out.println("newMap key:" + k + " is missing in oldMap - ADDED");
            resMap.put(k, new FileStateRow(k, (String) v, Activity.ADDED));
        } else {
            if (oldMap.get(k) != null && !oldMap.get(k).equals(v)) {
                System.out.println("newMap value change for key:" + k + ", old:" + oldMap.get(k) + ", new " + v);
                resMap.put(k, new FileStateRow(k, (String) v, Activity.MODIFIED));
            }
        }
    }); 

    oldMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (!newMap.containsKey(k)) {
            System.out.println("newMap key:" + k + " is missing in oldMap");
            resMap.put(k, new FileStateRow(k, (String) v, Activity.REMOVED));
        }
    }); 
    return resMap;
};
```

use:

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = .. // initiate and put values in..
Map<String, Object> map2 = .. // initiate and put values in..

// compare...
Map<String, FileStateRow> res = mapCompare.apply(map1, map2);

// print results
res.forEach((k, v) -> {
     System.out.println("key:" + k + ",  value " + v);
});
```

by yl.