# comparing the content of two HashMaps with set<> value

Tags: java, hashmap, set, equals

I have these two objects.

```
public Map<String, Set<RuleConditionBl>> countryToNonSplittedRules1 = new HashMap<>;
public Map<String, Set<RuleConditionBl>> countryToNonSplittedRules2 = new HashMap<>;
```

I have a test that compares these two

and even though their content is the same, i get false for

`countryToNonSplittedRules1.equals(countryToNonSplittedRules2);`

here is an example:

[image]

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814577/comparing-two-maps), so i'm not sure why doesn't this return `true`

```
public class RuleConditionBl {

public int weight;
public boolean isAll;
public List<String> countries;
public UserFlag userFlag;

@JsonIgnore
private Range<LocalDate> datesRange;

public String fromDate;
public String toDate;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        RuleConditionBl that = (RuleConditionBl) o;

        if (weight != that.weight) return false;
        if (isAll != that.isAll) return false;
        if (countries != null ? !countries.equals(that.countries) : that.countries != null) return false;
        if (userFlag != that.userFlag) return false;
        return datesRange != null ? datesRange.equals(that.datesRange) : that.datesRange == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
//        int result = weight;
        int result = 0;
        result = 31 * result + (isAll ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (countries != null ? countries.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (userFlag != null ? userFlag.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (datesRange != null ? datesRange.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

{
```

Comment: The one thing not observable in your screen shot: are you sure that the countries are equal? And to make that easier to debug: why don't you add a nice toString() and print out the contents of both maps?

Comment: Why did you delete your other question? **Again**, weight should be included in `hashCode`.

Comment: You shouldn't compare `UserFlag` instances with `userFlag != that.userFlag` (even though both appear to be null in your example, so it shouldn't affect the outcome). Use equals

Comment: Weight might be included in hashcode for completness, but omitting is not a reason for failure. You could do hashCode always being 1 and it should still work, as long equals is defined properly. I would be more worried about userFlag, if it is not enum - but as it is null in this case, it is not an issue here. I would suggest firing up a debugger, adding  breakpoint and going through equals method of RuleConditionB1 line by line, to see where it will exit.

Comment: If you are checking the equality of `UserFlag` you should use `equals` method and also if `UserFlag` some object with own properties it should also implement `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Comment: @Eran - if userFlag is enum, it is ok to compare it with operator equality.

Comment: @GhostCat the q was on-hold. i wanted to repost with more data

Comment: @Michael if i want to ignore a member equality should be more loose. so that's no the answer

Comment: @VPK UserFlag is an enum

Comment: @GhostCat what is the syntax?
`        assertThat(nonSplittedRulesSnapshotReal1, is(equalTo(nonSplittedRulesSnapshotReal2))); gives `Error:(103, 61) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> conforms to char` 
`

Comment: Range is not generic, so it cannot be parameterized with arguments. Can your code compile?

Comment: @GhostCat is get `Error:(103, 54) java: incompatible types: com.operations.blDto.NonSplittedRulesSnapshot cannot be converted to char`

Comment: @GhostCat i changed and `is()` compile but it doesn't give details

Comment: Too bad  .... then my only idea left is that full "toString()" implementation; to see if that reveals anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked a bit at your solution.

Your implementation is correct(ish).

First of all, `Range<LocalDate> datesRange` should not work if I am not mistaken.
`Range` is not generic, so it cannot be parameterized with arguments.(Please correct me if im wrong).

I change `Range<LocalDate> datesRange` to `List<LocalDate> datesRange`.

So besides that, your code is correct. I think your problem is the key values when you put your objects into `countryToNonSplittedRules1` and `countryToNonSplittedRules2`. The key values has to be the same, otherwise you cannot compare the two maps.

```
Map<String, Set<RuleConditionBl>> countryToNonSplittedRules1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Set<RuleConditionBl>> countryToNonSplittedRules2 = new HashMap<>();


Set<RuleConditionBl> s1 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<RuleConditionBl> s2 = new LinkedHashSet<>();

//Objects for s1
RuleConditionBl r1 = new RuleConditionBl();
r1.weight = 710;
r1.userFlag = null;
r1.isAll = false;

RuleConditionBl r3 = new RuleConditionBl();
r3.weight = 700;
r3.userFlag = null;
r3.isAll = false;

s1.add(r1);
s1.add(r3);

countryToNonSplittedRules1.put("r1", s1);

//Objects for s2
RuleConditionBl r2 = new RuleConditionBl();
r2.weight = 700;
r2.userFlag = null;
r2.isAll = false;

RuleConditionBl r4 = new RuleConditionBl();
r4.weight = 710;
r4.userFlag = null;
r4.isAll = false;

s2.add(r2);
s2.add(r4);

countryToNonSplittedRules2.put("r1", s2);

System.out.println(countryToNonSplittedRules1.equals(countryToNonSplittedRules2));
```

Output:

```
true
```

The order of the elements in `Set` does matter. According to the documentation:

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true
>   if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size,
>   and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This
>   ensures that the equals method works properly across different
>   implementations of the Set interface.

Comment: Well, comment for myself. My imported `Range`may not be the same import as OP is using, which is why he can parameterized `Range` with arguements.