# Java 8, compare two maps and return result

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I am comparing 2 maps **using Java 8 features** and based on condition wants to return the result. Using **.forEach** is showing compile time error and basically, the return is returning from Lambda expression and not from the loop. How can I return from the loop enclosing the lambda? 
**Note that I am not comparing for equality for the two map objects**

```
nMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
    if (!mMap.containsKey(k) || mMap.get(k) < v) {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Post the full code along with the loop

Comment: The `foreach` method accepted the `Comsumer`. It mean the void method. You can return in that.

Comment: that is the full code with the loop!

Comment: forEach(..) has argument of type consumer. Consumer interface has abstract method ( void accept(...).. so inshort your lambda should not return any thing from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break or return from Java 8 stream forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308193/break-or-return-from-java-8-stream-foreach)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814577/comparing-two-maps)

Comment: `for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : nMap.entrySet()) {
        V value = mMap.get(entry.getKey());
        if (value == null || value < entry.getValue()) {
            return -1;
        }
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `Stream` of the `entrySet()` and `anyMatch` instead of `forEach`:

```
boolean found = 
    nMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(e -> !mMap.containsKey(e.getKey()) || mMap.get(e.getKey()) < e.getValue());
if (found)
    return -1;
```

Comment: I want to check if all entries in nMap matches the condition.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi In that case, why did you return -1 the first time your condition was true? Anyway, if you want to check all entries, change anyMatch to allMatch

Comment: If you're only using `e.getKey()` in the lambda body, you could just use `nMap.keySet().stream()` instead. (And are you missing a `< v`?)

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, I must have accidentally deleted it when I formatted my answer. thanks

Comment: Alternatively: `boolean found = !mMap.keySet().containsAll(nMap.keySet())   || 
 nMap.entrySet().stream() .anyMatch(e -> mMap.get(e.getKey()) < e.getValue());`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using a `Stream` which filters the entries according to the given condition. The result of the streaming is an `Optional` which may contain a found `Entry`:

```
if (nMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> !mMap.containsKey(e.getKey()) || mMap.get(e.getKey()) < e.getValue())
        .findAny()
        .isPresent()) {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner Thx for spotting this.